# How do I set a firebase rule for deleting a record based on the record id?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I notice with Firebase rules you can have a $ variable to get a reference to the id of a record and then can use validation under that id. However, I can't seem to use this to restrict deletion of a record based on the id as this variable seems to be undefined (not sure how to confirm this) when the record is deleted. I'm guessing the validation needs to be one step up but I can't seem to get a reference to the ID unless I go under the $ variable.

an example:

```
"fruits": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        "$fruit": {
          ".validate": "root.child('fruitAccess/' + $fruit + '/' + auth.uid).exists() === true"
        }
}
```

In this situation the the person with access to the fruit can update and create it but cannot delete it as far as I have tried.. it just comes up "Permission Denied"

Thanks for any help :)

**** EDIT ***
The crux of the issue I'm having is that when a record is deleted as far as I can tell there isn't any way to get the ID or key of the record being deleted within the ruleset. Is there some method for getting the key of the "data" object? (as opposed to the newData object which you can get within the $ parameter but is null on deletion)

Comment: That behavior sounds exactly in line with the rules above: your `.validate` rule seems to require that the node itself exists and is owned by the current user. It sounds more like you want to put that rule into `.write`, so that only the original creator of the node can write to it.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I was hoping to put this into the ".write" under fruits but I'm not sure how to reference the ID from there (ie. where I've put $fruit as the ID) - sorry if this doesn't make sense

Comment: SOLVED: I think I was just being stupid. I have a feeling I was trying to update from one step up the tree and so the validation was failing. seems to work now that I get a reference directly to the id

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer and accept it? That will be helpful to others who might have a similar problem in the future.